# How do I get a presigned url from the javascript aws-sdk

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to generate a presigned url, but when I call the following, I get

> `s3.createPresignedPost()` is not a function

I am running `aws-sdk@2.3.14` and in [the docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#createPresignedPost-property) it clearly shows that `createPresignedPost()` is a function.  Here is my code:

```
getPresignedURL(bucket: string, key: string) {
      let s3 = new AWS.S3()

    let params = {
        Bucket: bucket,
      Fields: {
          key: key
      }
    }

    return s3.createPresignedPost(params, (err, data) => {
      if(err) {
        console.log(err)
      } else {
        console.log(data)
      }
    })
  }
```

Comment: Also note the availability of getSignedUrl() which is suitable for common operations (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#getSignedUrl-property)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

createPresignedPost was introduced at version 2.19.0 and the current version is 2.222.1.

[aws-sdk-js CHANGELOG](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#2190)

> feature: S3: Added an instance method to S3 clients to create POST
>   form data with presigned upload policies